# How does the equation make sense in case of an exponential distribution?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

$P(X>5|X>1)=P(X>4+1|X>1)=P(X>4)$

How does the above equation make sense in case of an exponential distribution?

Can anyone explain?

Comment: look up 'memoryless property' of the exponential distribution.

Comment: @dnqxt, thanks! got it.